# Issues doing a rollback in p4

Tags: version-control, perforce, p4v

I did a manual merge from branch A to B. It caused a build failure and I decided to rollback the manual merge. But when I tried to integrate from A to B again, it did not pick up the changes from A that I rolled back.

This seemed very weird - I was expecting things to work like in git, after a git revert.

Please let me know how I can get branch B back to the exact state it was before my manual merge and how I can successfully merge from A to B again. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the issue as well and had the same reaction.

Perforce is actually tracking what has been integrated between branches. You can display it with the command [p4 integrated](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_integrated.html).

In this case, the solution is to force the integration again with a `force` option.

In P4V, there is an option in the `Advanced` tab in the Merge menu, and by command line you have to use something like

```
p4 integrate -f ...
```

Similar questions and answers here : [Unable to integrate fully from main branch to feature branch, after backing out a previous messed-up integration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16309988/513198)

Comment: Thanks! Came across the option of force integrating with a revision range. Useful for really big branches.